# jQuery .hover after getting content with .get

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, So I've ade a static version of a piece of functionality and it works fine. When a user hovers over a div the content scrolls into it over a picture.

Now I needed multiple of these, accessible via tabs. To save loading time the content in these tabs (copies of the static version) are brought in with  a .get from another html file.

The structure of my separate html files is the same as the default tab which is working, I hover over the one stats there on page load and it works, once i change tab, the old content is faded out, and the new content is faded i correctly. All the class names are the same as is the structure, but when I hover over these elements that were brought in none of it runs.

Do I have to do something special for .hover to work on content that's dynamically brought in via .get after the page has loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to instantiate the hover after callback of the get method.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this before but calling the function. It didn't work, now i realize the function was out of scope because this code has yet to be fully integrated so that was indeed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use event delegation. Read up on the "Direct and Delegated Events" section [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
$("#tabs_content_container").on({
    mouseenter: function (e) {

    },
    mouseleave: function (e) {

    }
}, ".target-class");
```

where your HTML structure is something like:

```
<div id="tabs_container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="asdf.html">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="asdf2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs_content_container">

    </div>
</div>
```

and your code already is doing something like:

```
$("#tabs_container").on("click", function () {
    $.get($(this).attr("href"), function (data) {
        $("#tabs_content_container").html(data);
    });
});
```

Reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: I tried implementing it like that, but the same thing happens, it works on the default tab, but when i load in the new tab it doesn't work. (If a tab is already loaded its hidden then reshown instead of reloaded, and the default tab works if i go back to it so its not some other cod casing it either)

Comment: @ChrisMorris Well then you're going to have to provide your actual code, because this should work just fine. Are you sure you're using the correct form of `on` where event delegation takes place?